# Get the column difference in Excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I created a pivot table below and wanna calculate the count of 2016 - count of 2015 for each row. How can I do it in pivot table? Cheers

2015,2016 is value of a field 'year'.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can right click the cell and select 'Show Values As' and use 'Difference from ...' to covert the 2016 column into the difference. This method was using 2015 column as the base and meanwhile the 2015 column was invisible after the conversion. Ideally I can add extra column for difference in the pivot table.

Comment: So "Business cash flow" should have the value 2? And "Purchase used vehicle" should be "-67"? Is that it?

Comment: @Andreas right.

Comment: You can access the values in the pivot table just like any other cells. So if it's good enough you can just use `=C7-B7` (I guess the cash flow is on row 7). But if you want it to be a part of the pivot table I think you need to do the calculations with a helper column in the raw data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the instructions in the GIF below.
I've created a data table according to your questions and tested it.

- The main thing in this solution is the **Show Values As > Difference
  From** option in Pivot Table.
- Positive result means 2016 is bigger, negative result means 2015
  is bigger.
- I hid the irrelevant columns that were populated, I suggest you do
  the same.

[image: Pivot Table]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the count of year can be the additional column having equal value with count of account. If I expand the question to that: now I have 2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020 count of account. How I can get each pair of year diff which took each last year as the base? In the method above, it can only set up a single base year rather than going forward one by one.

Comment: Hi @LUSAQX, I think that what you want to acheive is available only by using VBA, I've tried doing it by using only the Pivot Table tools but I haven't found a reasonable solution. Perhaps someone else can answer this question if you open a new thread.

Comment: If you want to do year over year calculations, you need PowerPivot and DAX.